# proof of divergence of the serises

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

Let $\sum c_n$  be  a  series of  positive  numbers. Assume  that  $$\lim_n {{c_{n+1}}\over {c_n}} = r$$

If $0\lt r\lt 1$ then the series converges ; if $r\gt 1$ then diverges .

Now , if $r\gt 1$  then  we  have $$c_n \ge  c_N$$  for  $\forall n\ge N$ .

How do we have this $?$  Because , using the definition  of *limit* , I got $$c_{n+1}\lt ({r+\epsilon})c_n$$.

Comment: 1.  What's your question?  2.  The definition of limit tells you that for any $\varepsilon$, there exists an $N$ such that for any $n \geq N, (r-\varepsilon) c_n < c_{n+1} < (r+\varepsilon) c_n$.  It is the left inequality and not the right that gives you what you need.

Comment: @BrianTung : Yes , that is  my problem. Why do we have to consider the left one this time while for the $r\lt 1$ part we considered the right inequality $?$  Please explain that reason.

Comment: Because when $r > 1$, then what you want to show is that beyond a certain index $N$, everything gets bigger.  We show this by setting $\epsilon < r-1$; then we define $r' \equiv r-\varepsilon > 1$ and the left inequality tells you that $c_{n+1} > r' c_n$.  In other words, the $\{c_n\}$ diverge geometrically beyond $N$.  When $r < 1$, we want to show that everything gets smaller, so we use the *right* inequality, and define $r'' \equiv r+\varepsilon < 1$, and then $c_{n+1} < r'' c_n$; the $\{c_n\}$ converge geometrically beyond $N$.

Comment: For example, suppose $r = 2$.  Then the definition of the limit says that if we choose (say) $\varepsilon = 1/2$, then $3/2 < c_{n+1}/c_n < 5/2$ for $n \geq N$ (for some $N$).  We focus on the left inequality, which is equivalent to $c_{n+1} > (3/2) c_n$, so the $\{c_n\}$ diverge geometrically at a rate faster than $3/2$.

Comment: As $r + \epsilon$ can be larger than 1, than $c_{n+1} < (\text{something larger than 1)}\cdot c_n$. Doesn't tell us anything of any use.

Comment: @fleablood : That  is  what I needed . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because $r > 1$ there is $N \in \mathbb N$ so that $\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_{n}} \gt 1 , \forall n \ge N$. But $$\frac{c_{n}}{c_{N}} = \frac{c_{n}}{c_{n-1}}\frac{c_{n-1}}{c_{n-2}}...\frac{c_{N+1}}{c_{N}} \gt 1...1 = 1$$  for all $n>N$

Answer (score 0):

"$c_n \ge  c_N$ for $\forall n\ge N$" and "$c_{n+1}\lt ({r+\epsilon})c_n$" are not at all contradictory or in conflict.  As $r+ \epsilon > r > 1$, we can always have $c_n \lt c_{n+1} \lt (r + \epsilon)c_n$.  Indeed $M_i\cdot c_N > c_{N + i} \approx r^i C_N > C_N$ for *some* $M_i  > 1$.